# Binding vars to raw queries

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to bind vars to my raw query:

```
$data = $myModel->select( DB::raw('(3959 * acos(cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(:lng)) + sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(lat)))) as distance'), array(
        'lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng,
    ))->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')->having('distance', '<', $radius)
    ->get();
```

I've checked various SO posts which lead to this blog post:

http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

I still get the error:

```
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I need an instance - I have some if statements later on to determine some where clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must bind variables to `raw` method not `select`:

```
$select = "(3959 * acos(cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(:lng)) + sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(lat)))) as distance";
$data = $myModel->select( DB::raw($select,array(
    'lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng,
)))->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')->having('distance', '<', $radius)
->get();
```

Or use `selectRaw` method directly:

```
$data = $myModel->selectRaw($select,array(
    'lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng,
))->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')->having('distance', '<', $radius)
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this error now: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: select (3959 * acos(cos(radians(:lat)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(:lng)) + sin(radians(:lat)) * sin(radians(lat)))) as distance from `users` having `distance` < 1 order by `distance` asc)

Comment: @panthro Replace your named bindings with question marks (?): `$data = $myModel->selectRaw("(3959 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat)))) as distance",array($lat, $lng, $lat))->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')->having('distance', '<', $radius)
->get();` (Note the updated bindings array, as well).